# '/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share' is not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_HOME and XDG_DATA_DIRS

Tags: path, flatpak, xdg

Weird one, when I update flatpaks I get the following message in terminal:

```
Note that '/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share' is not in the search path
set by the XDG_DATA_HOME and XDG_DATA_DIRS
environment variables, so applications may not
be able to find it until you set them. The
directories currently searched are:

- /root/.local/share
```

However, if I run
`echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS`
I get the following:

```
/home/myname/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
```

Sort of new to linux, so am I missing something?

For context, I am using Fedora 37

Comment: Possibly you are updating flatpak as sudo, and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` is not defined for sudo. Try updating flatpaks without the `sudo`, I think it should be possible – something unclear to me as well.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1412825/1519798

Comment: It doesn't work for me as well, however there is a file `/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh` which sets XDG_DATA_DIRS, but it's not executed?